# Using low bitsize integral types like `Int8` and what they are for

Tags: haskell, integer, cpu-word, integer-promotion

Recently I've learned that every computation cycle performs on machine words which on most contemporary processors and OS'es are either 32-bit or 64-bit. So what are the benefits of using the smaller bit-size values like `Int16`, `Int8`, `Word8`? What are they exactly for? Is it storage reduction only?

I write a complex calculation program which consists of several modules but is interfaced by only a single function which returns a `Word64` value, so the whole program results in `Word64` value. I'm interested in the answer to this question because inside this program I found myself utilizing a lot of different `Integral` types like `Word16` and `Word8` to represent small entities, and seeing that they quite often got converted with `fromIntegral` got me thinking: was I making a mistake there and what was the exact benefit of those types which I not knowing about got blindly attracted by? Did it make sense at all to utilize other integral types and evetually convert them with `fromIntegral` or maybe I should have just used `Word64` everywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These smaller types give you a memory reduction only when you store them in unboxed arrays or similar. There, each will take as many bits as indicated by the type suffix.

In general use, they all take exactly as much storage as an `Int` or `Word`, the main difference is that the values are automatically narrowed to the appropriate bit size when using fixed-width types, and there are (still) more optimisations (in the form of rewrite rules mainly) for `Int` and `Word` than for `Int8` etc., so some operations will be slower using those.

Concerning the question whether to use `Word64` throughout or to use smaller types, that depends. On a 64-bit system, when compiling with optimisations, the performance of `Word` and `Word64` should mostly be the same since where it matters both should be unpacked and the work is done on the raw machine `Word#`. But there probably still are a few rules for `Word` that have no `Word64` counterpart yet, so perhaps there is a difference after all. On a 32-bit system, most operations on `Word64` are implemented via C calls, so there operations on `Word64` are *much* slower than operations on `Word`.

So depending on what is more important, simplicity of code or performance on different systems, either

1. use `Word64` throughout: simple code, good performance on 64-bit systems
2. use `Word` as long as your values are guaranteed to fit into 32 bits and transform to `Word64` at the latest safe moment: more complicated code, but better performance on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! Please consider the comment I left to the ehird's answer. Since generally your answers are similar it addresses you too.

Comment: Updated answer. Depending on your situation and aims, I may disagree with ehird.

Comment: @DanielFischer is your statement about when you get a memory reduction still true in base-4.16? The definition of `Int8` changed to the following in that version: `data {-# CTYPE "HsInt8" #-} Int8 = I8# Int8#`, whereas it was `I8# Int#` in earlier versions. There have been similar changes to all the other fixed-size signed/unsigned integral types (although the code comments still claim that the sub-64-bit types are represented in the same way as `Int`/`Word`).

Answer (score 8):

In GHC, the fixed-size integral types all take up a full machine word, so there's no space savings to be had. Using machine-word-sized types (i.e. `Int` and `Word`) will probably be faster than the fixed-size types in most cases, but using a fixed-size integral type will be faster than doing explicit wrap-around.

You should choose the appropriate type for the range of values you're using. `maxBound :: Word8` is 255, `255 + 1 :: Word8` is 0 — and if you're dealing with octets, that's exactly what you want. (For instance, `ByteString`s are defined as storing `Word8`s.)

If you just have some integers that don't need a specific number of bits, and the calculations you're doing aren't going to overflow, just use `Int` or `Word` (or even `Integer`). Fixed-size types are less common than the regular integral types because, most of the time, you don't need a specific size.

So, don't use them for performance; use them if you're looking for their specific semantics: fixed-size integral types with defined overflow behaviour.

Comment: As always you and Daniel to the rescue! ) Okay, so generally `Int` and `Word` are better than those small types - I get it. But what about the second question I was pointing out: will it still be more effective to perform all the intrinsic operations in `Word` if I know that in the end I would still evetually have to upsample those values to `Word64`, or does it make sense in this scenario to just use `Word64` everywhere from the beginning and thus spare some cycles by eliminating the `fromIntegral` conversions?

Comment: If you're aiming to produce a `Word64` result, I would use `Word64` for the intermediate computations, too. On a 64-bit machine, it'll be a machine word, so there shouldn't be any performance problems, and `fromIntegral` will be a NOP at runtime.

Comment: No space savings?  I thought that with bangpatterns they would save space in data constructors.